# Reversing Single Linked list using Recursion

Tags: python, oop, recursion, linked-list, reverse

I have made a function that reverses the singly linked list using Recursive method.
However I am having some difficulty executing my below code:

```
class node:
    def __init__(self,data=None):
        self.next=None
        self.data=data

class linked_list:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head=node()

def append(self,data):
    new_node=node(data)
    cur_node=self.head
    while (cur_node.next!=None):
        cur_node=cur_node.next
    cur_node.next=new_node
    return cur_node.data

def display(self):
    elements=[]
    cur_node=self.head
    while(cur_node.next!=None):
        cur_node=cur_node.next
        elements.append(cur_node.data)
    print(elements)

def reverseRecursive(self,prev_code,cur_node):
    if cur_node.next!=None:
        reverseRecursive(cur_node,cur_node.next)
        cur_node.next=prev_node
    else:
        self.head=cur_node
    return
lst1=linked_list()
lst1.display()
lst1.append(1)
lst1.append(3)
lst1.append(5)
lst1.append(7)
lst1.display()
lst1.reverseRecursive(None,_____)
lst1.display()
```

What should I pass the second argument in reverseRecursive function/method so that I can execute it?

As a second argument, I want to simply pass the **head** node of a linked list. But I don't know how to get the head node from the **init method** of  the class **linked_list**

I have tried several things but I'm not able to resolve it. Maybe I am not very good at OOP concepts. Can anyone please help me in resolving this?

Comment: I think it is `prev_node` and not `prev_code` and also `self.reverseRecursive(....)` inside the definition of `reverseRecursive`

Comment: You have **indentation errors**! You don't have to pass a `class member` to a `class method`. Simply use `cur_node = self.head` on top of `def reverseRecursive`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linked list is a recursive structure, and so using it with functional style will yield the best results. In your program, you have implemented a linked list using procedural style and [mutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) nodes – you change the values of `data` and `next` over time. While this might feel like an intuitive approach, I'd like to focus on an *immutable* discipline that frees us from crippling state complexity.

First, we fix the `node` constructor function. We set both properties when constructing new nodes because they will not change later in the program –

```
class node:
  def __init__ (self, data, next):
    self.data = data
    self.next = next
```

Then a `linked_list` is just a single node constructed by a particular convention:

- `node.data` hold's the node's data
- `node.next` is either:

  - another `linked_list`
  - *or*, `None`, representing the end of the list

We begin with the constructor for `linked_list` –

```
class linked_list:
  def __init__ (self, node = None):
    self.node = node

  # ...
```

And implement `is_empty`, `head`, and `tail` [properties](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) to abstract away `node` –

```
class linked_list:
  def __init__ (self, node = None):
    self.node = node

  @property
  def is_empty (self):
    return self.node is None

  @property
  def head (self):
    if self.is_empty:
      raise Exception ("cannot get head of an empty list")
    else:
      return self.node.data

  @property
  def tail (self):
    if self.is_empty:
      raise Exception ("cannot get tail of an empty list")
    else:
      return self.node.next
```

Now the use of a `node` is completely abstracted, and we can write higher level list behaviors by using our new properties –

```
class linked_list:
  ... 

  def length (self):
    if self.is_empty:
      return 0
    else:
      return 1 + self.tail.length()
```

Above, we see it's very easy to talk about our list through use of its properties. Before we go further, let's see how we can construct lists and visualize them using `print`. For object-to-string conversion, we use [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) –

```
class linked_list:
  ... 

  def add (self, x):
    return linked_list (node (x, self))

  def __str__ (self):
    if self.is_empty:
      return "None"
    else:
      return str (self.head) + " -> " + str (self.tail)

ls = linked_list().add('A').add('B').add('C')
print (ls)
# C -> B -> A -> None

print (ls.length())
# 3
```

Remember, because we've built an immutable linked list, `add` does *not* change the list it was called upon –

```
ls = linked_list().add('A').add('B').add('C')
print (ls)
# C -> B -> A -> None

print (ls.add('D'))
# D -> C -> B -> A -> None

print (ls)
# C -> B -> A -> None
```

Finally, we can implement `reverse` –

```
class linked_list:

  # ...

  def reverse (self):
    def loop (ls, acc):
      if ls.is_empty:
        return acc
      else:
        return loop (ls.tail, acc.add(ls.head))
    return loop (self, linked_list())

ls = linked_list().add('A').add('B').add('C')
print (ls)
# C -> B -> A -> None

print (ls.reverse())
# A -> B -> C -> None
```

Reversing the list does not mutate it

```
print (ls)
# C -> B -> A -> None

print (ls.reverse())
# A -> B -> C -> None

print (ls)
# C -> B -> A -> None
```